# Meaning of these sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs

> The train **has been** cancelled.
>
> The train **is** cancelled.
>
> The train **has** cancelled.

Which one is the correct sentence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a train is cancelled, it is an occurrance that extends from that moment forward, since trains aren't "uncancelled", though they could be "postponed". So this one is OK:

> The Train has been cancelled.

However,

> The Train is cancelled.

does not work logically in this context. I can't say its specifically wrong because the train *is* cancelled, but I don't think anyone would say it this way.

And when you say:

> The Train has cancelled.

this cannot stand by itself since this form requires a direct object, like:

> The snow *has cancelled* my travel plans.

Answer (score 0):

> The Train has been cancelled.

You would hear this when the speaker is formally communicating that the particular train service has been cancelled.

> The Train is cancelled.

This is a casual expression of the same thing and is more frequently used in close proximity, either time or physically.

> The Train has cancelled.

I cannot think of a reasonable scenario where this would be used.

Answer (score 0):

**The Train has been cancelled.** This is correct; you are using the past perfect tense. This tense indicates that an action was completed (finished or "perfected") at some point in the past before something else happened

**The Train is cancelled.** This is correct; you are using the past participle to describe the train. You can use this phrase in a more informal way and to describe what is happening right now or very recently; the train is cancelled means that the train has literally just been cancelled as we are speaking.

**The Train has cancelled.** This sentence is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score -1):

> The Train has been cancelled. - YES
>
> The Train is cancelled. - NO
>
> The Train has cancelled. - NO

Use the first one. It is grammatically correct and it sounds very fluent.

Answer (score -1):

The train has cancelled doesn't make sense but cancel is transitive verb and will use object.and also train by itself can't anything.